# iOS UISlider - change price value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I've been looking for quite some time for a solution but couldn't find the right answer for me.

I'm trying to set two sliders - one for minimum price and one for maximum price, and then create labels that will contain the prices. Both sliders will change the labels' values accordingly. I've yet to find a good way to display a price and alter it with the sliders, could you please help me?

Thank you and I'm truly sorry if this is a stupid question, I have just started iOS a few weeks ago. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Just review the basic examples and coco for UISlider, cheers.  You can do it all easily in XIB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the maximumValue property of UISlider, if you set maximumValue is 1000,then the ranges of slider`s value is 0~1000.

is this your problem?

Comment: This is what I meant since in the documentation i saw 0.0-1.0. anyway now it worked so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you would **Google** for basic examples first, you would find these resources:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html
- [how to use the UISlider and how to set the slider on a particular values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609992/how-to-use-the-uislider-and-how-to-set-the-slider-on-a-particular-values) http://www.devfright.com/uislider-tutorial/
- http://www.xprogress.com/post-35-uislider-tutorial-example-how-to-use-slider-in-iphone-sdk-xcode/
- http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/better-code-uislider-basics-for-apple-ios/

So what you have to do is follow the steps below:

1. Create both `UISlider`'s and `UILabel`'s on Storyboard/Interface Builder.
2. Connect them with code in your View Controller as IBOutlet's.
3. Add Target actions to `UISlider`'s - `UIControlEventValueChanged`.
4. Update UILabel's text when that target action is fired.

**While this seems much, it is practically a very basic iOS development technique. View the links above for more detailed explanation.**

*And remember, always do your own research first, before presenting a problem to StackOverflow. This question is very basic and every programmer should be able to solve it, without asking others to solve it for you.*

Comment: Thank you for the reply and for the info. But that's not what i meant exactly. I got all the stuff you said working, my issue is different. I couldn't find a good way to show a label with a price (could be just a normal int) in relation to the sliders value (that ranges between 0.0-1.0). I understand the confusion my post made. But I just asked for a help with a good representation for the price through the sliders value. I googled that before I asked but I couldn't find something to answer **my** issue. thanks again tho.

Comment: If you have slider's value between 0.0 and 1.0, you can get your label's value with the following code: `label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", (minimumValue + (maximumValue - minimumValue) * slider.value];`